# Run function in alert popup script function php

Tags: php, encryption, dialog, popup, dropbox

I have Encryption Method & Upload Method, After I click the encryption button, i would like to have a popup dialog that states if i want to upload to dropbox after encryption, the dialog box consist of yes or no. If No, i would only want the file to be encrypted, if Yes, i would want the file to encrypt and upload to dropbox.

Currently my method is seperated, I would like to join them together by using the popup button.

Thanks!

This is the popup script function:

```
<script>
function confirmDelete(delUrl) {
  if (confirm("Do you want to upload to Dropbox?")) {
   document.location = delUrl;
  }
}

</script>

<a href="javascript:confirmDelete('delete.page?id=1')">Encrypt</a>
```

How do I run this function in the popup script if click yes?

**Encryption Form**

```
<form>
<b>Select file to encrypt:</b>
<br>
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<br>
<input type="submit" value=" Encrypt ">

</form>
```

**Upload Form**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<b>Select file to upload:</b>
<br>
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="path" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Upload ">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a hidden input into the form to distinguish the form submission type.
Add a `onsubmit` handler to the form and then check `$_POST['action_type']` upon submission.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmUpload() {
  if (confirm("Do you want to upload to Dropbox?")) { // click 'Yes'
    document.getElementById('action_type').value = 'upload'
  }else{ // click 'No'
    document.getElementById('action_type').value = 'encrypt'
  }
  return true;
}
</script>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return confirmUpload()">
    <b>Select file to upload or encypt:</b>
    <br>
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="path" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Upload or Encrypt" >
    <input type="hidden" id="action_type" name="action_type" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: It does upload it successfully, but it does not encrypt. I try adding in the encryption process after this line

 if (confirm("Do you want to upload to Dropbox?")) { // click 'Yes'
    document.getElementById('action_type').value = 'upload'

But still it does not work.

Comment: @SarahPhil, the action type `upload` means both upload and encrypt. you would need to call the encrypt procedure if `upload`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    function confirmDelete(delUrl) {
      confirm="Do you want to upload to Dropbox?"
if(confirm) {
       document.location = delUrl;
      }
    }

    </script>


    <a href="javascript:: void(0);" onclick="return confirmDelete('delete.page?id=1');>Encrypt</a>
```

this might work.